# Double integral over the circle

Tags: integration

I came across the following equation. How to prove it?

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \operatorname{ln}{\left(\frac{1}{|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\theta'}|}\right)} d\theta d\theta' = 0.$$

Comment: One way is to use Green's theorem  $$I = \oint\oint_{\partial D \times \partial D} \frac{\ln|z-w|^2}{2zw}dzdw = \iint\limits_{D\times \partial D} \oint\frac{2}{zw(\bar{z}-\bar{w})}dx\wedge dy\wedge dw$$

Comment: I understand how to get to the l.h.s, but not the r.h.s. Also, if I admit the r.h.s I don’t see how it gives 0

Comment: Even without integrating over $\theta^\prime$, $\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\frac{1}{|e^{i\theta}-e^{i\theta^\prime}|}d\theta=0$ for all $\theta^\prime$. This reduces to $\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(2\sin\tfrac12\theta)d\theta=0$, which is provable from the famous $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x)dx=-\tfrac12\pi\ln2$.